# How to limit Node refernce field selection to user own nodes?

Tags: 7, users, nodes

If there are 3 content types that user can create A, B and C. A is main content, B and C  are secondary content types, each time B or C created they automatically have reference to A. My goal is to make possible optionally create reference on C node to B, by displaying check list (when C node is edited/created) with B nodes from same A node. This nodes can have only 1 author and only 1 main A node, so C2 can not be referenced to A1 or B1, only to A2-B2, even if they have same author.

What can be the best way to create such reference filter/pernissions?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a View of type References, and then configure the Node Reference field to use that View.

So you configure the View to only list nodes that the current user is the author of, and any additional filters you want.  That should give you what you want.

Look for this area when you edit the Node Reference field:
[image]